# Perl Execution error

Tags: perl, cygwin, perl-module

I just upgraded my Active Perl Version. If I call any Perl script through the windows command prompt or through UltraEdit (Text Editor) I am able to execute it perfectly but if I call it through cygwin terminal I am getting this error -

> Can't locate Date/Pcalc.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14
>   /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/5.14
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 .) at Test.pl line 3. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at Test.pl line 3.

Even though the PCalc module is installed, it is looking in the wrong path for the PCalc.pm file. Any thoughts on how to resolve this and what it means ?

Any help is much appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: Completely uninstalling and re-installing Perl worked. Once Perl is installed the ENV variables and PATH are set to that version of Perl. So when we manually upgrade, we need to go into some of the registers and manually update them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the correct Perl ? i.e. are you picking up the Cygwin Perl installation as opposed to the ActiveState version ?

If you're referencing the correct Perl, then you should amend your `PERL5LIB` environment variable to reflect your local installation of `Date/Pcalc.pm`. See [here](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations) for more details.